# Rails 3 routes 'match' syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to route

```
[PUT] http:// foo /data/base_states/?id=8
```

to my controller, preferably with this style of definition:

```
`match '/data/base_state:id' => 'base_state#create_or_update', via: [:put]`
```

How?

It seems there are many different ways to define routes, with documentation somewhat lacking. Would be interested in any other suggested syntax (that works) as well.

---

No idea why the suggested routes aren't working, this is my routes.rb and controller ...

**config/routes.rb**

```
EntwineBe::Application.routes.draw do

  namespace :data, defaults: {format: :json} do
      resources :event_categories
      resources :state_categories
      resources :base_events
      resources :base_states

      match '/block/:bock' => 'block#show', via: [:get]  # curiously, this WORKS AS EXPECTED with GET http://foo/data/block/foo

      match '/base_state/:id' => 'base_states#create_or_update', via: [:put]
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/data/base_states_controller.rb**

```
class Data::BaseStatesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_base_state, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @base_states = BaseState.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @base_state = BaseState.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create  # typical REST is that this is PUT
    @base_state = BaseState.new(base_state_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @base_state.save
        format.html { redirect_to @base_state, notice: 'Base state was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: data_base_state_url(@base_state) }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @base_state.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def create_or_update
    logger.info "WTF"
  end

  def destroy
    @base_state.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to base_states_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_base_state
      @base_state = BaseState.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def base_state_params
      params.require(:base_state).permit(:foo, :bar)
    end
end
```

**Relevant output of 'rake routes'**

```
            data GET    /data/block/:block(.:format)          data/code_block#show {:format=>:json}
                 PUT    /data/base_state/:id(.:format)            data/base_states#create_or_update {:format=>:json}
                 PUT    /data/base_state:id(.:format)             base_state#create_or_update {:format=>:json}
```

**example call**

```
$.ajax({'type':'PUT', 'url':'/data/base_state?id=8'})
$.ajax({'type':'PUT', 'url':'/data/base_state/?id=8'})

$.ajax({'type':'PUT', 'url':'/data/base_state?id=8.json'}) // not that expect it to need / I want to have .json
$.ajax({'type':'PUT', 'url':'/data/base_state/?id=8.json'}) // not that expect it to need / I want to have .json
```

--> **404!**

Comment: try the url '/data/base_state/8.json'

Comment: @Slicedpan that actually works :) ! sweet. if you answer I'll accept. ... how can i get it to respond without the .json though?

Comment: you are missing the data type for the ajax call: `dataType: 'json'` then you don't have to write `.json` at the end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Add `defaults: {format: :json}` to your route.

```
match '/data/base_state:id' => 'base_state#create_or_update', via: [:put], defaults: {format: :json}
```

Comment: That's what I expect to work too ... but it doesn't.. I updated the question with full routes.rb and the controller in question.  arg.

Answer (score 0):

```
put '/data/base_state:id' => 'base_state#create_or_update', defaults: { format: :json }
```

Comment: That's what I expect to work too ... but it doesn't.. I updated the question with full routes.rb and the controller in question.  arg.

Answer (score 0):

```
put "data/base_state:id(.:format)" => 'base_state#create_or_update'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late with this!

If your route is `/data/base_state/:id`, then the url you use to view the matching resource with id 8 say is `/data/base_state/8.json`.

As spas correctly points out, if you set the correct datatype in the ajax call, `dataType: 'json'`, then you do not need to add the .json at the end of the URL